# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpDir' when installing AWS SDK for Node.js using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to install the SDK for Javascript using npm on my EC2 instance.

I have Node.js installed (v 0.10.33) and npm installed as well. I have been able to install other things such as Express.js without issue. However when trying to install the AWS SDK for Node I get the following error:

```
node.js:201
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tmpDir'
at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/osenv.js:49:13
at Object.tmpdir (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/osenv.js:14:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/defaults.js:76:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:368:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:4:18)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this error or what I can do to fix it?

--
Edit: result of running node and os = require('os');, os.tmpDir();

```
> os = require('os');
{ endianness: [Function],
  hostname: [Function],
  loadavg: [Function],
  uptime: [Function],
  freemem: [Function],
  totalmem: [Function],
  cpus: [Function],
  type: [Function],
  release: [Function],
  networkInterfaces: [Function],
  arch: [Function],
  platform: [Function],
  tmpdir: [Function],
  tmpDir: [Function],
  getNetworkInterfaces: [Function: deprecated],
  EOL: '\n' }
> os.tmpDir();
'/tmp'
```

Comment: i'd guess that node is not installed properly.

Comment: try running node and running: os = require('os'); os.tmpDir();

Comment: what happens if you do that?

Comment: I added the results to the question @Transcendence

Comment: idk what's on your osenv.js, but on mine at line 49 it's os.tmpDir(). i am running 0.10.36 it looks like your os module does have the tmpDir function, so you might try debugging that file with console.log statements, to see what the os module has when installing the sdk. i assume you ran `npm install aws-sdk`?